# How to write Elasticsearch query aggregating the total of a field, grouped by a value in "linked" documents?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am just getting started with Elasticsearch 5 and have a question about structuring data and writing a query.

Let’s say you have a movie subscription service with normal and premium memberships.

Here is a sample of data generated by user activity:

```
[
    {
        "eventType": "sessionInfo",
        "userType": "premium",
        "sessionGroupID": 1
    },
    {
        "eventType": "mediaPlay",
        "productSKU": "starwars",
        "sessionGroupID": 1,
        "elapsed": 200
    },
    {
        "eventType": "sessionInfo",
        "userType": "premium",
        "sessionGroupID": 2
    },
    {
        "eventType": "mediaPlay",
        "productSKU": "xmen",
        "sessionGroupID": 2,
        "elapsed": 500
    },
    {
        "eventType": "sessionInfo",
        "userType": "normal",
        "sessionGroupID": 3
    },
    {
        "eventType": "mediaPlay",
        "productSKU": "xmen",
        "sessionGroupID": 3,
        "elapsed": 10
    },
    {
        "eventType": "sessionInfo",
        "userType": "normal",
        "sessionGroupID": 4
    },
    {
        "eventType": "mediaPlay",
        "productSKU": "xmen",
        "sessionGroupID": 4,
        "elapsed": 100
    },
    {
        "eventType": "sessionInfo",
        "userType": "normal",
        "sessionGroupID": 5
    },
    {
        "eventType": "mediaPlay",
        "productSKU": "xmen",
        "sessionGroupID": 5,
        "elapsed": 5
    },
    {
        "eventType": "mediaPlay",
        "productSKU": "starwars",
        "sessionGroupID": 5,
        "elapsed": 25
    }
]
```

You can see that there are two “eventTypes”:

- “sessionInfo” documents that have information common to an entire
  user session
- “mediaPlay” documents that store how many seconds of a
  movie was viewed.

(Each “mediaPlay” event contains the sessionGroupID so it can be associated with that session.)

---

### **Question #1:**

Given tens of millions of documents total, how would you write a query that totaled the elapsed viewing time of each movie, grouped by userType?

**Desired query results:**

```
premium users - total of "elapsed":
    xmen: 500
    starwars: 200

normal users - total of "elapsed":
    xmen: 115
    starwars: 25
```

---

### **Question #2:**

If the data is not structured optimally for such a query, what would be the ideal structure?

- For example, would it be better to put the “sessionInfo” documents in a separate Elasticsearch “index” or “type” than the user activity logs?
- Would it be better to nest the “mediaPlay” events inside the sessionInfo documents?

Thanks for any and all guidance and advice!

Comment: For question one, I think, you can solve the issue with subaggregation. First one for users and second one is movies. https://www.elastic.co/blog/intro-to-aggregations-pt-2-sub-aggregations If you did not try, I can create an example for you. On the other hand, I have not understand where you store mediaPlay entities.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I have looked at sub-aggregations, but have not been able to write the correct syntax to deliver the results above.

To answer your question, "mediaPlay" events are stored in the same place as all other events, just a flat Elasticsearch database. All events are store in the same index and type.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change (I know it will take time for change structure but will good for your application in future) your data structure like below then you don't need to use sub-aggregation.

```
[
    {
        "eventType": "sessionInfo",
        "userType": "premium",
        "sessionGroupID": 1
    },
    {
        "eventType": "mediaPlay",
        "productSKU": "starwars",
        "userType": "premium",
        "sessionGroupID": 1,
        "elapsed": 200
    },
    {
        "eventType": "sessionInfo",
        "userType": "normal",
        "sessionGroupID": 3
    },
    {
        "eventType": "mediaPlay",
        "productSKU": "xmen",
        "userType": "normal",
        "sessionGroupID": 3,
        "elapsed": 10
    }
]
```

Otherwise I can create a query with sub-aggregation but it will be take time each time to execute.

```
Subhash Kumar | Associate Manager - IT
Daffodil Software Ltd.
```

Comment: It does look like denormalization would provide the simplest solution, as well as the fastest queries, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @JamesJensen : Welcome dear! Have you changed the structure? Is it working good for you? If you need any another help then please shared.